# Positional arguments in lmfit cannot be SciPy CubicSpline datatype

Tags: python, scipy, lmfit

Problem:
If the array of *positional arguments* I plug into lmfit `minimize()` is obtained from `scipy.interpolate.CubicSpline`.

I get the following error:

```py
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'CubicSpline' and 'float'
```

The `*` operation is used in my model function where I multiply the positional argument array (`x`)  with a fitting parameter (`pars['a']`) as shown below. Basically, lmfit thinks (`x_list`) is a type `CubicSpline` even though it is an array of floats.

**My Code**:

```py
import scipy.interpolate as scpi
import numpy as np
from lmfit import Parameters, minimize

A = np.linspace(0,1,100)
B = A**2 

y_list = np.linspace(1,100,100)
x_list = scpi.CubicSpline(A, B)

def model(pars, x, data=None):
    model = x*pars['a']
    if data is None:
        return model
    return model - data

fit_params = Parameters()   
fit_params.add('a',  value = 1., min = 0.0, vary=True)
coeff = minimize(model, 
                 fit_params, 
                 args=(x_list(A),), 
                 kws={'data': y_list}, #cut off distance
                 method='basinhopping', 
             )
```

Here is what I have tried so far:

- `type(x_list)` shows it is an array of floats
- `x_list*0.1` works in a cell
- type casting `x_list` as an array of floats does not fix the problem: `x_list = np.asarray([float(j) for j in x_list])`

Comment: What are `A` and `B`? Where is `lmfit` used?

Comment: A and B are data arrays obtained from previous calculations. Ultimately, I want the fit for this previous data to turn into the x data for my model function. (A and B can be any data). lmfit is used for the functions Parameters() as well as minimize().

Comment: After `x_list = scpi.CubicSpline(A, B)`, `x_list` is a 'CubicSpline', as the error says.  Read the docs to learn what you can do with that.   `x_list*1.` produces your error.

Answer (score 1):

Your `x_list` is not a list, it's a CubicSpline object.